# Get meta tag value with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to get one value from all meta tags:

```
Elements elements= document.getElementsByTag("meta");
```

I will get these elements:

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/0daLqxVdiOGXvHI1R5aUFf_6znVlBHMturM9SXnpOQagADdYJDycyPzT-btcntR4jW4=w600-h300-pc0xffffff-pd">
<meta name="appstore:developer_url" content="http://www.verylittlenightmares.com">
<meta name="appstore:bundle_id" content="eu.bandainamcoent.verylittlenightmares">
<meta name="appstore:store_id" content="eu.bandainamcoent.verylittlenightmares">
<meta itemprop="price" content="200,00&nbsp;$">
<meta itemprop="url" content="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.bandainamcoent.verylittlenightmares&amp;rdid=eu.bandainamcoent.verylittlenightmares&amp;feature=md&amp;offerId">
```

How can i get value (200,00 $) from this attribute?

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="200,00&nbsp;$">
```

Comment: Write some code and iterate through them?  I don’t program in that language but perhaps show what you have tried and maybe someone will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String getPrice(Document document) {

    Elements elements= document.getElementsByTag("meta");

    for (Element metaTag : elements) {
        String content = metaTag.attr("content");
        String itemprop = metaTag.attr("itemprop");

        if ("price".equals(itemprop)) {
            return content;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this, without need to iterate over all the `meta` elements, assuming you have only one node with `itemprop=price`:

```
Element meta = doc.select("meta[itemprop=price]").first();        
System.out.println(meta.attr("content"));
```

The output is 200,00 $' as desired.